# Android designer not rendernig properly in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-designer

Since its installation, the android designer is not rendering properly because of which I have problems designing the UI. This is the screenshot that says it all.

[image]

I have repaired the installation and also uninstalled and the reinstalled the VS2017 but still it is not showing up correctly.

Comment: Use Android Studio for build/design the UI, android designer not rendering properly in Visual Studio Enterprise too ;)

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/13380/designer-view-for-android-layout-axml-doesnt-displ.html

Comment: I can't use Android Studio because I have only 4GB RAM

Comment: So you have to wait, maybe VS team decide to work more on this part, but I don't think so, I reported this on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com and https://forums.xamarin.com already, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check for updates and install, I dont have that problem with VS 2017 enterprise